# Jmeter make request with logged session

Tags: java, session, jmeter

I need to test my REST service with jMeter. I need to login first and then call REST services several times.

**!!Http Cookie Manager does not work as expected!!**

The problem:

HTTP Request to login - Here I need to get JSESSIONID

```
POST http://localhost:8080/xxx/index.faces

POST data:
form-login=form-login&j_username=xxx&j_password=yyy

[no cookies] - ???

Cabeceras de petición:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 76
Host: localhost:8080
```

On browser it returns:

```
JSESSIONID=E9A3BC9C290549F32EB278133337450A; Path=/xxx/; HttpOnly
```

HTTP Cookie Manager - It is supposed to save cookies

HTTP Request to REST - Fails, cause JSESSIONID is not set

```
GET http://localhost:8080/xxx/rest/yyy/list

[no cookies]

Cabeceras de petición:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Host: localhost:8080
```

[image: jmeter configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've figured out why is not working.
Cookie Manager works perfectly.
Login page actually expects `javax.faces.ViewState` id in order to pass jmeter request into login provider. Once, I've resolved it (), `javax.faces.ViewState` becomes stateless and let me login succesfully. Thanks for help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the cookie manager before the request?

Comment: Just put it before the sampler Controlador Simple, not in the sampler. And it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add an HTTP Header Manager to the request and add `JSESSIONID`  as the name and  `${COOKIE__JSESSIONID}` as the value in the "Headers Stored in Header Manager" section.

This will pass the value of JSESSIONID from the cookie to the HTTP Request Headers.

Comment: Nope. ${COOKIE__JSESSIONID} is not recovered :(